# Call function with usinf if statement javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My if statement is not working correctly.
How to call function in if statement?

Please look at the code,what's wrong?
Thanks

```
charName = prompt("Write only your character name?");
oppName = prompt("Write only your opponent name");  

(function MyFunction(){
  $('#game').prepend('<img class="vs" src="images/image.jpg" />')
        $("#vs").animate({
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",           
        }, 7000,

         function() {
          $("#vs").css("display","none");
          $("#pauseImg").show(),
          $("#ChooseChar").show(),
          $("#pauseImg").animate({width: "4%"},2500);
          })

        $("#pauseImg").click(function(){
             $("#pausewindow").show();
             $("#pausewindow").animate({width: "45%",height: "65%"},1000)
             $("#pauseImg").hide();
        })
});

if (charName == "player1" && oppName == "player2") {
        MyFunction(); 
      alert("Let's Start");
     }
```

Comment: Should `#vs`  select the prepended element? If yes, the selector should be `.vs`, class selector.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't that the `if` block is wrong but rather that you've not declared your function, you've written a *function expression* instead. You'll either need to assign the expression to a variable or write it as a *function declaration*

Change

```
(function MyFunction(){
    // ..
});
```

to

```
// function declaration
function MyFunction () {
    // ..
}
```

or

```
// var'd function expression
var MyFunction = (function MyFunction(){
    // ..
});
```

Please note that only (`var`d) *identifiers* and *function declarations* get hoisted - using a *function expression* will mean it's only defined after the line it's written on